# Thinking about 26

Tags: elementary-number-theory

26 is, to my knowledge, the only number which is the arithmetic mean of a square and a cube, and $27 - 25 = 5 - 3$ (the differences are the same).

How could you find all integers (or prove that there are infinite) that are the geometric or arithmetic mean of a square and a cube?

Similarly how could you find all integers $m,n$ such that  $m \neq n \neq 0$ (or prove that there are infinite) where $|(m^3-n^2)| = |(m-n)|$?

Thank you!

Comment: Set $m-n-d\iff m=n+d$

Comment: Geometric mean is easy: $\sqrt{m^3n^2}=n\sqrt{m^3}$ is an integer iff $m^3$, and therefore $m$, is a perfect square: $m=k^2$. In that case, we get $\sqrt{m^3n^2}=k^3n$. Therefore, all integer multiples of cubes are geometric means of a cube and a square. For instance, $24=2^3\cdot3$ is the geometric mean of $(2^2)^3=64$ and $3^2=9$.

Comment: Ah I looked at that method, but foolishly was considering whether they were coprime or not when it is not necessary

Answer (score 1):

Your equation $|m^3-n^2|=|m-n|$ is equivalent to the pair of equations
$m^3-n^2=m-n$ or $m^3-n^2=n-m$. Each of these is a elliptic curve, and by Siegel's theorem each has a finite number of integer solutions $(m,n)$.

Finding all solutions is another matter...